# Compare maxima of two Bernouilli experiments

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, sample, extreme-value

I am looking at the following question -- which has already been solved for the case of Gaussian samples [Compare maxima of two Gaussian samples](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82725/compare-maxima-of-two-gaussian-samples) but I am unable to find a similar answer for the binomial case.

Let $X_1,X_2,...X_m$ independent binomial random variables distributed according to B($n, x$), and $ Y_1,Y_2,...Y_m$ independent binomial random variables distributed according to B($n, y$), $x > y > 0$, what is the probability that 
$\max_{1 \le i \le m} X_i \ge \max_{1 \le i \le m} Y_i$? Would there be a good approximation to this probability?

Comment: Do you really mean B$(n,0)$? In which case $y_i=0$ with probability one.

Comment: (1) Except when $m=1$ (and even then) there isn't a nice closed-form expression (barring the trivial cases where the $Y_j$ have the same distribution as the $X_i$ or one or both of the parameters is $0$ or $1$).  (2) The referenced thread gives an *approximation* rather than a solution.  (3) What @Xi'an said.

Comment: Sorry, indeed I didn't mean B(n,0). I would also be happy with an approximation. I've just edited the text to take the comments into account